# PHP insert array of values

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I haven't been able to get my INSERT statement to work. I know the problem is how I'm trying to bind the parameters. INSERT was working before I added parameter binding.

```
$inventoryQuery = "INSERT INTO inventory (Whse, Product, Description,
QtyOnHand, QtyUnavail, BinLoc1, BinLoc2, GLCost, OnhandTotalValue,
UnavailTotalValue, GrandTotalValue) 
    VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?');";
// execute INSERT statement
$conn = $GLOBALS['conn'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare($inventoryQuery);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $sqlV[0]);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $sqlV[1]);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $sqlV[2]);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $sqlV[3]);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $sqlV[4]);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $sqlV[5]);
$stmt->bindParam(7, $sqlV[6]);
$stmt->bindParam(8, $sqlV[7]);
$stmt->bindParam(9, $sqlV[8]);
$stmt->bindParam(10, $sqlV[9]);
$stmt->bindParam(11, $sqlV[10]);

$stmt->execute();
```

Output using var_dump($stmt):

> object(PDOStatement)[2]
>     public 'queryString' => string 'INSERT INTO inventory (Whse,Product,Description,QtyOnHand,QtyUnavail,BinLoc1,BinLoc2,GLCost,OnhandTotalValue,UnavailTotalValue,GrandTotalValue) 
>                       VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);' (length=192)

I have seen and tried many ways to handle binding parameters. And now my head is swimming. If you could provide a solution and an explanation, I would be so happy.

**Solution from all info provided:**

```
    try{
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $inventoryQuery = "INSERT INTO inventory ($sqlField) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    // execute INSERT statement
    $conn = $GLOBALS['conn'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($inventoryQuery);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $sqlV[0]);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $sqlV[1]);
    $stmt->bindValue(3, $sqlV[2]);
    $stmt->bindValue(4, ((int) ((float) $sqlV[3])));
    $stmt->bindValue(5, ((int) ((float) $sqlV[4])));
    $stmt->bindValue(6, $sqlV[5]);
    $stmt->bindValue(7, $sqlV[6]);
    $stmt->bindValue(8, ((float) $sqlV[7]));
    $stmt->bindValue(9, ((float) $sqlV[8]));
    $stmt->bindValue(10, ((float) $sqlV[9]));
    $stmt->bindValue(11, ((float) $sqlV[10]));

    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    var_dump($ex);
}
```

Thanks to everyone that helped!

Comment: You are trying to insert multiple values into one column.

Comment: I edited the post to show the value of $sqlField variable, which was a string containing all the column names of the table.

Comment: @BrentConnor I need to know how all the `$sqlV` are being populated from. In the meantime, try an `array` method `$stmt->execute(array($sqlV[0], $sqlV[1]), etc.);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go with incorrect column types in this one. Try surrounding your execution in a try-catch block and make sure SQL isn't throwing any errors. If it is, it will likely show you exactly what you need to do.

Here's an example:

```
try
{
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $ex)
{
    // log this object or just the error messages
    log($ex->getMessage()); // Assuming you have some sort of global logger set up.
}
```

P.s. You can remove the semi colon in your query string. Being at the end shouldn't hurt anything, but if you were to add anything after it, it would terminate your statement early.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code:

```
('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')
```

remove the quotes

```
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: I removed the quotes, but its still not making it to the database. if I use print_r on $stmt after execute, it outputs: [   PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => INSERT INTO inventory (Whse,Product,Description,QtyOnHand,QtyUnavail,BinLoc1,BinLoc2,GLCost,OnhandTotalValue,UnavailTotalValue,GrandTotalValue) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); )   ]

Comment: @BrentConnor What errors are you getting? Plus can you var_dump your query?

Comment: No errors. var_dump result: object(PDOStatement)[2]
  public 'queryString' => string 'INSERT INTO inventory (Whse,Product,Description,QtyOnHand,QtyUnavail,BinLoc1,BinLoc2,GLCost,OnhandTotalValue,UnavailTotalValue,GrandTotalValue) 
     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);' (length=192)

Comment: @BrentConnor Instead of `bindParam` try `bindValue`

Comment: changed to bindValue. No affect.

Comment: @BrentConnor Yeah, this one's a real head scratcher. Try to prepare it first 
`$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT... )";` 
and remove the before last semi-colon `);";` to `)";`

Comment: @BrentConnor Plus, make sure all of your column names are indeed correct, and no typos. If one is mispelled, the whole query will fail. Check also for column types and their lengths; that could also be a contributing factor.

Comment: @BrentConnor I see you found your solution, great! The person wrote *"but if you were to add anything after it, it would terminate your statement early."* which is what I meant earlier about that extra semi-colon in your query `);";` - Glad it got resolved, *cheers*